# How to dismiss and push new ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my application there is a floating button. Its function is to open available screens from anywhere.

> Scenario

Suppose I have 4 screens and in each screen their is floating Button.

```
1. Home Screen
2. Services Screen
3. Contact Screen
4. Events
```

Now suppose I have opened all screens. And currently I am in Contact Screen and I want to go to Services.

Then I have to push services again thus creating the object of Services Screen. This creates a problem as if the user gooes 10 times to Services then 10 new objects will be created.

How can I implement this scenario ?

My Code:

```
 if([sender tag]==1)
   {
      [push home];
   }

 else if([sender tag]==2)
   {
      [push services];
   }
else if([sender tag]==3)
   {
      [push Contact];
   }
 else

 {
     [push events];
 }
```

Comment: how exactly do you open screens from anywhere ? where are all these screens contained ? Are these represented by `UIViewController` instances ?

Comment: Yes all are UIViewController Instances

Comment: Post the code that gets executed when your `floating button` is tapped please ?

Comment: @NSUser have you considered UITabBarController?

Comment: @rptwsthi I can't use tab bar as my application developed I have to add a floating button

Comment: what does the `push` method do ? Comeon noone can help you if you don't provide enough context

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
UIViewController *popViewController = //assign here Services Screen or what view you want to back

BOOL isExist = NO;
for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isEqual:popViewController]) {
        isExist = YES;//exist view controller. so you should not create a new one
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

if (isExist==NO) {//not exist view controller. so you should create a new one
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Bro I want to pop and push new screen based on user selection.

Comment: and What if I am in home screen and then I open services

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Dear users, stop downvoting answers without giving any explanation. UITabBarController is designed specifically for the aforementioned kind of accessibility across the application. Also, using UITabBarController will ensure that everything it contains will be instantiated once and presented on demand without any risk of UI state corruption.

Answer (score 0):

@NSUser, sorry for not answering your exact problem, but I would recommend using `UIPageViewController` for "hosting" and presenting your content view controllers one at a time. Here is a conceptual [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3) from Apple with essential description and how-to's. Good luck.